# Merge Dataframes by index of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, jsonlite

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
test <- 'https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability'
data <- fromJSON(test)
a <- as.data.frame(data$items$carpark_data)
b <- a[[1]]
c <- bind_rows(b, .id = "carpark_info")
```

Upon inspection, I noticed a has 2047 rows and c has 2214 rows.

For instance, a in row 107 (1 observation) has 3 corresponding values (observations) in c

How can I full_join them so a will have the same number of rows as c?

Comment: you need a right/left  join to c. and not a full join

Comment: What about a full-join isn't working? Or right-join?

Comment: It seems to me that you just want to have a complete data frame with the data that is in a column-list as new columns. If this is is the case, you could just make `a %>% tidyr::unnest(cols = carpark_info)` to have a complete data frame with your 2214 rows.

Comment: Hi,you can use merge to get your result ```data <- merge(c,a,by=c('carpark_info'),all.x=T)```Hope this will help.What i have observed with tag 'carpark_info' in dataframe 'a' should be numeric as it is in a.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, eventually found a way to do with left join as @Onyambu suggested.